# GROUP BY to List<> with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to using Linq so I don't understand some things or its syntax. I want to group a list and then loop through it with foreach, like my logic below. Obviously my logic doesn't work.

My code:

```
var final = finalv.Union(finalc);
final = final.GroupBy(x => x.Clave);

foreach (var articulo in final)
{
    Articulo articulo2 = new Articulo();
    articulo2.ArtID = articulo.ArtID;
    articulo2.Clave = articulo.Clave;
    articulo2.ClaveAlterna = articulo.ClaveAlterna;
    lista.Add(articulo2);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The line `final = final.GroupBy(x => x.Clave)` is clearly wrong.

Comment: What do you expect from answer? The `var articulo` in foreach is a 'list' where those had same `Clave` value, so you basically do another loop inside `foreach` to access items

Comment: Try `foreach (var grouping in final.GroupBy(x => x.Clave))` if it's just the syntax error that trips you.

Answer (score 0):

First, such usage is syntactically consistent with this overloaded method of `GroupBy`: `GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>)`, and it will return a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>>` variable.

That means, if you run `final.GroupBy(x => x.Clave)`, let's assume he returns `finalWithGrouped`, then `finalWithGrouped.Key` is the key and `finalWithGrouped.ToList()` is a collection of all variables with the same key(at here, it is with the same `Clave`).

And for your code, try this:

```
var final = finalv.Union(finalc);
var finalWithGrouped = final.GroupBy(x => x.Clave);
    
foreach (var articulosWithSameClavePair in finalWithGrouped)
{
    var clave = articulosWithSameClavePair.Key;
    var articulos = articulosWithSameClavePair.ToList();
        
    foreach(var articulo in articulos)
    {
        Articulo articulo2 = new Articulo();
        articulo2.ArtID = articulo.ArtID;
        articulo2.Clave = articulo.Clave;
        articulo2.ClaveAlterna = articulo.ClaveAlterna;
        lista.Add(articulo2);
    }
}
```

I suggest you read some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) of using `GroupBy`.

Comment: Please don't link off to external sites without first putting the salient content in your answer. Also it would be useful to explain why your suggested code might be useful to the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Thanks for the suggestion, I've made changes to the answer, sorry for the just simple answer.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is group products and then apply a groupby to them. The solution you present is a step towards the ultimate solution. But after the foreach it returns more than expected. Or can the result of the groupby be added directly to a list(List<>)?

Comment: @CesarOliverJiménez - Can you please try to explain what you're trying to achieve? Saying that it "returns more than expected" or "can the result of the groupby be added directly to a list" doesn't tell us what you're actually trying to do. A clear statement would allow us to help.

Answer (score -2):

When you group a list, it will return a key and groued list and you are trying reach a single property of a list.

When you group an data, you can convert it to dictionary, It is not nessesary but better way for me. You can try this code:

```
    var final = finalv.Union(finalc);
    final = final.GroupBy(x => x.Clave).ToDictionary(s=> s.Key, s=> s.ToList();
    
    foreach (var articulo in final)
    {
        foreach (var articuloItem in articulo.value)
       {
        Articulo articulo2 = new Articulo();
        articulo2.ArtID = articuloItem.ArtID;
        articulo2.Clave = articuloItem.Clave;
        articulo2.ClaveAlterna = articuloItem.ClaveAlterna;
        lista.Add(articulo2);
       }
    }
```

Comment: That returns a less convenient type than `GroupBy`.

Comment: And your code is nowhere near tested. It's got a lot of syntax errors.

Comment: And, really, your answer doesn't actually answer the question. You've just made a `ToDictionary` suggestion that doesn't give the OP any answer as to why his code didn't work.

Comment: Please test your code. Also please explain the value of using this code that `lista = final.OrderBy(x => x.Clave).ToList()` wouldn't achieve?